# Extra repos for Fedora. Confused about EPEL vs rpmfusion

Tags: linux, fedora

I use Fedora 15.

Not sure if I understand how EPEL is related to rpmfusion.

Is EPEL a branch of rpmfusion or are they a completely different projects?

What other major 3-rd party repositories would you recommend for Fedora?

Comment: The only other one I install is [Livna](http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/rpm.livna.org/), because I use the [sole package](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html) it continues to provide that RPMFusion refuses to quite often.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **EPEL** is a repository of extra bits for Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and its offshoots, such as CentOS). The EPEL repository is maintained by the Fedora project.

  http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ
- **RPM Fusion** is a repository of extra bits that can be used with Fedora OR Red Hat Enterprise Linux OR Red Hat Enterprise Linux + EPEL and is also maintained by the Fedora project.

  http://rpmfusion.org/FAQ

Answer (score 2):

EPEL is for people using RedHat Enterprise Linux (it stands for Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) not for people using Fedora.